# Using Modernizr in Foundation 3 to detect if device is a phone?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, modernizr

I am building a responsive site in Foundation 3.

The one remaining sticking point is leaderboard ads.  I want to have one ad slot that displays leaderboard ads on desktop and tablet, but a phone-specific ad on phones (since leaderboard will obviously not fit).

I talked with Doubleclick (our ad vendor) and they suggested using a javascript browser sniffer inline at the point where the ad goes to load one or the other ad call.

Since Foundation uses Modernizr, I was looking for a way to leverage it to detect which ad to serve.  But looking at its docs, I don't see any.  Touch is the only relates one, but that would include tablets; I only want to target phones.

Is there a was to do this in Modernizr, or should I just resort to navigator.userAgent?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Modernizr for simple check, you may check for Touch support

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {
   // mobile
} else {
   // desktop
}
```

Of course, it's not the most correct solution as there are mobile phones that don't support touch events. If you want to have a more thorough check of mobile devices, the right way to go now is checking `navigator.userAgent` I guess.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said "touch" will be true for all mobile devices I need just smartphones.  I have used touch often if I just want desktop vs. mobile.  except this time i need more specificity.

Comment: Oops, missed the "touch" in your question. Then I guess your best bet is the userAgent string in navigator object. Then again, if "space" is  your concern (leaderboard ads in desktop and tablet), why don't you check for screen size as well?

Answer (score 0):

Going down the user-agent road is probably overkill.

> I only want to target phones

Even with Modernizrs feature detection, *accurately* separating phones from tablets would be a headache.

If your core issue is displaying the correct sized ad, why don't you just use the users viewport to determine the ad size?

e.g.

```
if($(window).width() < desktopAdWidth){
      // do mobile ad stuff..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Modernizr.mq() to evaluate a combination of screen size and pixel density.
I believe anything with a pixel density higher than 1.0 is mobile.

Also according to the documentation the touch detection is not reliable as WebOS does not report touch, and I suspect future versions of browsers on Windows 8 touch capable PCs will start reporting touch.

Comment: It is not uncommon for a Desktop/Laptop to have a higher pixel density than 1. I can think of Apple's Retina Macbook Pros and the Chrome Pixel.